# two network interfaces in LXC → Systemd is blocked for 5min (services dead)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, systemd, proxmox

I use proxmox to virtualize some LXCs. Recently I wanted to add a second interface on a Debian 11 LXC build of Turnkey ... but there is a weird problem with systemd. When I configure two static interfaces, systemctl stops working or something like that. Services like apache2 pihole or postfix become dead and when I start them nothing happens, there are no outputs and logs .... nothing. I have to configure the second interface via DHCP to make it work. Five minutes after startup everything works fine ... there is a service that stops according to journalctl, but I do not know what to do :(

```
-- Journal begins at Sun 2023-03-26 20:45:28 CEST, ends at Thu 2023-03-30 04:48:44 CEST. --
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Journal started
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/edf9400ae9bb497ebdae3986c16f8a90) is 8.0M, max 1.2G, 1.2G free.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm mount[49]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: permission denied.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/edf9400ae9bb497ebdae3986c16f8a90 is 3.742ms for 4 entries.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/edf9400ae9bb497ebdae3986c16f8a90) is 16.0M, max 4.0G, 3.9G free.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: Failed to increase receive buffer size for general netlink socket, ignoring: Operation not permitted
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: Enumeration completed
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth0: Lost carrier
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth0: Gained carrier
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Forwarding to syslog missed 1 messages.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being skipped.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Discard unused blocks once a week being skipped.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Daily rotation of log files.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Daily man-db regeneration.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Listening on OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm cron[99]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm cron[99]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available being skipped.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting User Login Management...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Wait for Network to be Configured.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[105]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[103]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[104]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[111]: (root) CMD (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[112]: (root) CMD (   PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/" pihole updatechecker reboot)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[113]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate --state /var/lib/logrotate/pihole /etc/pihole/logrotate)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth1: Link UP
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth1: Gained carrier
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm rsyslogd[108]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.2102.0]
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm rsyslogd[108]: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Permission denied.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm rsyslogd[108]: activation of module imklog failed [v8.2102.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm rsyslogd[108]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0" x-pid="108" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm sudo[115]:     root : PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get update
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm sudo[115]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm CRON[104]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm ifup[122]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm ifup[61]: ifup: failed to bring up eth1
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-resolved[90]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-resolved[90]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-resolved[90]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-resolved[90]: Using system hostname 'dns-sturm'.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd-logind[109]: New seat seat0.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started User Login Management.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Unbound DNS server...
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Permit User Sessions.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Console Getty.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Container Getty on /dev/tty1.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Container Getty on /dev/tty2.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm unbound[158]: [1680143482] unbound[158:0] warning: so-rcvbuf 1048576 was not granted. Got 425984. To fix: start with root permissions(linux) or sysctl bigger net.core.rmem_max(linux) or kern.ipc.maxsockbuf(bsd) values.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Unbound DNS server.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Unbound DNS server via resolvconf being skipped.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm unbound[158]: [158:0] info: start of service (unbound 1.13.1).
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: e2scrub_reap.service: Succeeded.
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[115]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[162]:     root : PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -y
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[162]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[162]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[166]:     root : PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get autoremove -y
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[166]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm sudo[166]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:23 dns-sturm CRON[105]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:24 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 30 04:31:24 dns-sturm systemd-networkd[62]: eth1: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 30 04:31:34 dns-sturm login[151]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by LOGIN(uid=0)
Mar 30 04:31:34 dns-sturm login[151]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to create session: Seat has no VTs but VT number not 0
Mar 30 04:31:34 dns-sturm login[209]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'
Mar 30 04:31:52 dns-sturm CRON[103]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:31:52 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Forwarding to syslog missed 45 messages.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: ifupdown-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: ifupdown-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for network to be configured by ifupdown.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Pi-hole FTL...
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Pi-hole FTL.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] Using log file /var/log/pihole/FTL.log
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] ########## FTL started on dns-sturm! ##########
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] FTL branch: master
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] FTL version: v5.22
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] FTL commit: eb197891
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] FTL date: 2023-03-22 21:21:35 +0000
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] FTL user: pihole
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] Compiled for x86_64 (compiled on CI) using gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] Starting config file parsing (/etc/pihole/pihole-FTL.conf)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    SOCKET_LISTENING: only local
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    AAAA_QUERY_ANALYSIS: Show AAAA queries
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    MAXDBDAYS: max age for stored queries is 365 days
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    RESOLVE_IPV6: Resolve IPv6 addresses
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    RESOLVE_IPV4: Resolve IPv4 addresses
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    DBINTERVAL: saving to DB file every minute
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    DBFILE: Using /etc/pihole/pihole-FTL.db
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    MAXLOGAGE: Importing up to 24.0 hours of log data
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    PRIVACYLEVEL: Set to 0
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    IGNORE_LOCALHOST: Show queries from localhost
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCKINGMODE: Null IPs for blocked domains
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    ANALYZE_ONLY_A_AND_AAAA: Disabled. Analyzing all queries
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    DBIMPORT: Importing history from database
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    PIDFILE: Using /run/pihole-FTL.pid
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    SOCKETFILE: Using /run/pihole/FTL.sock
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    SETUPVARSFILE: Using /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    MACVENDORDB: Using /etc/pihole/macvendor.db
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    GRAVITYDB: Using /etc/pihole/gravity.db
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    PARSE_ARP_CACHE: Active
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Forwarding to syslog missed 16 messages.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    CNAME_DEEP_INSPECT: Active
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    DELAY_STARTUP: No delay requested.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCK_ESNI: Enabled, blocking _esni.{blocked domain}
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    NICE: Cannot change niceness to -10 (permission denied)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    MAXNETAGE: Removing IP addresses and host names from network table after 365 days
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    NAMES_FROM_NETDB: Enabled, trying to get names from network database
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    EDNS0_ECS: Overwrite client from ECS information
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    REFRESH_HOSTNAMES: Periodically refreshing IPv4 names
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    RATE_LIMIT: Rate-limiting client making more than 10000 queries in 60 seconds
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    LOCAL_IPV4: Automatic interface-dependent detection of address
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    LOCAL_IPV6: Automatic interface-dependent detection of address
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCK_IPV4: Automatic interface-dependent detection of address
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCK_IPV6: Automatic interface-dependent detection of address
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    SHOW_DNSSEC: Enabled, showing automatically generated DNSSEC queries
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    MOZILLA_CANARY: Enabled
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    PIHOLE_PTR: internal PTR generation enabled (pi.hole)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    ADDR2LINE: Enabled
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    REPLY_WHEN_BUSY: Drop queries when the database is busy
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCK_TTL: 2 seconds
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    BLOCK_ICLOUD_PR: Enabled
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    CHECK_LOAD: Enabled
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    CHECK_SHMEM: Warning if shared-memory usage exceeds 90%
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M]    CHECK_DISK: Warning if certain disk usage exceeds 90%
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M] Finished config file parsing
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm pihole-FTL[1197]: [2023-03-30 04:36:23.025 1197M
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/postfix-script[1383]: starting the Postfix mail system
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/master[1385]: daemon started -- version 3.5.17, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/pickup[1386]: 334A822095A: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Succeeded.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Startup finished in 5min 662ms.
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/cleanup[1390]: 334A822095A: message-id=<20230330023623.334A822095A@dns-sturm.localdomain>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 334A822095A: from=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, size=1781, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/pickup[1386]: 344ED220933: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/cleanup[1390]: 344ED220933: message-id=<20230330023623.344ED220933@dns-sturm.localdomain>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 344ED220933: from=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, size=919, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/pickup[1386]: 349FF220936: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/cleanup[1390]: 349FF220936: message-id=<20230330023623.349FF220936@dns-sturm.localdomain>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 349FF220936: from=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, size=919, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/pickup[1386]: 34ED7220932: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/cleanup[1390]: 34ED7220932: message-id=<20230330023623.34ED7220932@dns-sturm.localdomain>
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 34ED7220932: from=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, size=1781, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/local[1392]: 334A822095A: to=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=300, delays=300/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 334A822095A: removed
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/local[1392]: 344ED220933: to=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=270, delays=270/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 344ED220933: removed
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/local[1392]: 34ED7220932: to=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=589, delays=589/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 30 04:36:23 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 34ED7220932: removed
Mar 30 04:36:24 dns-sturm postfix/local[1393]: 349FF220936: to=<root@dns-sturm.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=561, delays=560/0/0/0.97, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 30 04:36:24 dns-sturm postfix/qmgr[1387]: 349FF220936: removed
Mar 30 04:37:23 dns-sturm systemd-journald[45]: Forwarding to syslog missed 24 messages.
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm CRON[1407]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm CRON[1408]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm CRON[1407]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Mar 30 04:39:01 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Mar 30 04:46:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Mar 30 04:46:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Mar 30 04:46:23 dns-sturm systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Mar 30 04:47:52 dns-sturm sudo[1497]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl
Mar 30 04:47:52 dns-sturm sudo[1498]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 30 04:47:52 dns-sturm sudo[1498]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 30 04:48:44 dns-sturm sudo[1510]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b
Mar 30 04:48:44 dns-sturm sudo[1510]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
```

And here my network configuration:

```
root@dns-sturm:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if415: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:0c:09:0b:63:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.4.49.1/20 brd 10.4.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::700c:9ff:fe0b:633e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1@if419: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:6e:82:7f:2b:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.4.49.2/20 brd 10.4.63.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c46e:82ff:fe7f:2bd3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@dns-sturm:~# 
root@dns-sturm:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.4.49.1/20
        gateway 10.4.48.3

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.4.49.2/20
        gateway 10.4.48.3
```

Maybe someone has the same problem or knows what to do ... :)
Jonathan

Comment: Aside from this, do you actually need two interfaces here? They're both on the same subnet; they could be two addresses on a single interface.

Answer (score 0):

> Services like apache2 pihole or postfix become dead and when I start them nothing happens, there are no outputs and logs

Their start jobs are probably waiting for another service. Use `systemctl list-jobs`.

> When I configure two static interfaces

Note the failure to actually configure them:

```
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm ifup[122]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 30 04:31:22 dns-sturm ifup[61]: ifup: failed to bring up eth1
```

The `gateway` parameter is not actually interface-specific once it gets converted to a route; the unique key is just "destination + gateway + metric". If you have two identical routes with the same gateway and the same metric (i.e. cost value), the second one won't be added successfully.

It becomes a problem when you're using Debian's ifupdown, which 1) does not pay attention to global configuration beyond the one interface it's asked to work with, 2) handles such situations in a rather bad way – it aborts whenever any operation fails, even though the goal has already been achieved (e.g. route already present or interface already up).

One way to avoid this would be to manually configure a different `metric` parameter for each interface. Another is to avoid having the duplicate configuration in the first place, removing one of the `gateway` parameters as they're mostly redundant. (In fact, you could just configure both IP addresses on the *same* interface, having two `iface eth0` blocks and avoiding the need for eth1.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion, the same problem also occurs when configuring two different networks.
I accidentally uploaded the wrong config but the log and so on look 1 to 1 the same with different networks.
Sorry also for the late reply, I am assuming I will receive a mail ... :)